# How can I provide dynamic filtering on an entity collection?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, filtering, observablecollection

I have a class ShipmentsCollection that inherits ObservableCollection which contains shipment objects (entities).  This is displayed in a listbox on my ShipmentsView UserControl.  My intent is to allow a user to type into a textbox above the list and filter the list with items that contain that string, as well as filter based on several checkbox and radiobutton based options (Delivery status and orderby direction).

I have tried this several ways, but none seem very elegant or really functional.  Things I have tried follows:

- Put ShipmentsCollection into a CollectionViewSource and filtered via predicate.  Could not figure out a good way to make the filter auto update based on user typing or option change.
- Refactored as a Class that Inherits collectionViewSource and tried to declare directly in XAML but got the following error: "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid".  Tried fixing but could not find solution that worked.
- Refactored to inherit from CollectionView, implemented filter logic, in event handler in codebehind.  Still trying to figure out how I can get the filter string to the event handler without naming the filtertext textbox control.

Anyone got some good ideas in regard to implementing this functionality in an MVVM design pattern.  I expect to have at most 200 objects in the list, so it will not be an enormous filter operation.

Cory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first option would be the one I would suggest. To get the auto-filter to work based on typing, I'd do something like a SearchString property in my ViewModel, bind the textbox text to that, and set the UpdateSourceTrigger in the binding to PropertyChanged so it will call the SearchString PropertyChanged event every time a key is typed instead of waiting until the box loses focus.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

ViewModel: With the above property set to PropertyChanged, the "Set" method gets called anytime a key is typed instead of just when the textbox loses focus.

```
private string _searchString;
public string SearchString
{
    get { return _searchString; }
    set
    {
        if (_searchString != value)
        {
            _searchString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchString");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will check it out and see what I can make of it!

Comment: It works!  It is alive!  I have created life from nothing but code (with the tremendous help of Rachel).  Thank you Rachel.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is closed and old. but for someone like me searching for dynamic filtering, can refer to the following link

https://github.com/lokeshlal/WPFDynamicFilters

the above example creates filters for each entity based on the attribute defined on property of entity model.

As an example:

1. Define an attribute for filters

   ```
   public class FilterAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public FilterAttribute() { }
       public string FilterLabel { get; set; }
       public object FilterValue { get; set; }
       public string FilterKey { get; set; }
       public Type FilterDataType { get; set; }
       public bool IsDropDown { get; set; }
       public string DropDownList { get; set; }
       public List<object> ObjectDropDownList { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Apply the above attribute in model properties

   ```
   public class GridModel
   {
       [Filter(FilterLabel = "Id",
           FilterKey = "Id",
           IsDropDown = false,
           FilterDataType = typeof(int))]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [Filter(FilterLabel = "Name",
           FilterKey = "Name",
           IsDropDown = false,
           FilterDataType = typeof(string))]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       [Filter(FilterLabel = "Country",
           FilterKey = "Country",
           IsDropDown = true,
           FilterDataType = typeof(int),
           DropDownList = "Country")]
       public string Country { get; set; }
       [Filter(FilterLabel = "Address",
           FilterKey = "Address",
           IsDropDown = false,
           FilterDataType = typeof(string))]
       public string Address { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Define the model that will bind to the drop down type

   ```
   public class Country
   {
       public int Id { get; set; } // id will be used for value
       public string Name { get; set; } // Name will be used for display value
   }
   ```
4. ViewModel of actual View

   ```
   public class FilterViewModel
   {
       public ICommand CheckFiltersCommand { get; set; }
       public FilterViewModel()
       {
           CheckFiltersCommand = new DelegateCommand(GetFilters);
           GridSource = new List<GridModel>();
           GridSource.Add(new GridModel() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", Country = "Denmark" });
           GridSource.Add(new GridModel() { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", Country = "India" });
           GridSource.Add(new GridModel() { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", Country = "Australia" });
           GridSource.Add(new GridModel() { Id = 4, Name = "Name4", Country = "India" });
           GridSource.Add(new GridModel() { Id = 5, Name = "Name5", Country = "Australia" });
           GridSource.Add(new GridModel() { Id = 6, Name = "Name6", Country = "Hongkong" });

           FilterControlViewModel = new FilterControlViewModel();
           FilterControlViewModel.FilterDetails = new List<FilterAttribute>();

           foreach (var property in typeof(GridModel).GetProperties())
           {
               if (property.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(FilterAttribute)).Any())
               {
                   var attribute = (FilterAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(FilterAttribute)).First();
                   FilterControlViewModel.FilterDetails.Add(attribute);
               }
           }
       }

       private void GetFilters()
       {
           FilterCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();
           foreach (var filter in FilterControlViewModel.FilterDetails)
           {
               if (filter.IsDropDown)
               {
                   if (filter.FilterValue != null)
                       FilterCollection.Add(filter.FilterKey, filter.FilterValue.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(filter.FilterValue));
               }
               else
               {
                   FilterCollection.Add(filter.FilterKey, filter.FilterValue);
               }
           }

           MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", FilterCollection.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + Convert.ToString(m.Value)).ToArray()));
       }

       public List<GridModel> GridSource { get; set; }

       public Dictionary<string, object> FilterCollection { get; set; }

       public FilterControlViewModel FilterControlViewModel { get; set; }
   }
   ```

In the above view model 'FilterControlViewModel' property will iterate all property of model and collect the filter information of the properties.
This same property will be assigned to the user control as explained in xaml file below

```
    <Window x:Class="WPFDynamicFilters.GridWithFilters"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDynamicFilters"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="gridwithfilters" Height="481.239" Width="858.171">
        <Grid>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="FilterGrid" Height="209" Width="830">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gold"/>
                <local:Filter DataContext="{Binding FilterControlViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding GridSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,294,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="146" Width="830"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Check Filters" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Command="{Binding CheckFiltersCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Filter control will take all the attributes and render the control using itemscontrol

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WPFDynamicFilters.Filter"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDynamicFilters"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="40" 
                 >
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TStringTemplate">
                <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilterKey}" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="TxtFieldValue" 
                         Text="{Binding FilterValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                         RenderTransformOrigin="-9.3,0.5" Width="200" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TIntegerTemplate">
                <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilterKey}" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="IntFieldValue" 
                         Text="{Binding FilterValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                         RenderTransformOrigin="-9.3,0.5" Width="200" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TDropDownTemplate">
                <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilterKey}" />
                    <ComboBox 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding FilterValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding FilterValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectDropDownList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                 RenderTransformOrigin="-9.3,0.5" Width="200" FontSize="16" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:FilterTemplateSelector x:Key="FilterTemplateSelector" 
                    StringTemplate="{StaticResource TStringTemplate}"
                    IntegerTemplate="{StaticResource TIntegerTemplate}"
                    DropDownTemplate="{StaticResource TDropDownTemplate}"
                    />
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilterDetails}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl 
                                Content="{Binding}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FilterTemplateSelector}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Finally define the template selector

```
public class FilterTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate IntegerTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DropDownTemplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
                     DependencyObject container)
        {
            var filter = (item as FilterAttribute);
            if (filter == null) return StringTemplate;

            if (!filter.IsDropDown)
            {
                switch (filter.FilterDataType.Name.ToLower())
                {
                    case "int32":
                    case "int64":
                        return IntegerTemplate;
                    case "string":
                        return StringTemplate;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // display drop down
                switch (filter.DropDownList)
                {
                    case "Country":
                        filter.ObjectDropDownList = GetDropDown.GetCountries().ToList<object>();
                        break;
                }
                return DropDownTemplate;
            }

            return StringTemplate;
        }
    }
```